# Can we get Active Directory property named Employee ID using Office365Users connector inside Power App

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

Inside our active directory we have a property named "Employee ID" as follow:-

[image]

so inside our PowerApp form i want to get the value of this property,,, but i checked the Office365Users connector  @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/connection-office365-users seems it does not provide such a data.. so how i can get the Employee ID property inside our PowerApp form? this ID is different than the ID which we can get using this formula  `Office365Users.MyProfile().Id` which will return the internal GUID of the user, and not the number shown above.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (As of 2021-09-27), there is no Out of the box connector for Power Apps that will get you employeeId. The reason is that we need to query the beta version of Microsoft Graph, as it is not query-able in the version 1.0 of the endpoint. There is hope, the new Office 365 Users Connector has a new version of [Get my profile (V2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#get-my-profile-(v2)) that queries the new version of the Graph interface, and allows us to select `employeeId`, as well as [almost everything else available](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties). The downside is that it returns a [GraphUser_V1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365users/#graphuser_v1) object. So, even though the API call returns the `employeeId`, since Power Apps is Strongly Typed, we cannot reference `employeeId` as it's not a part of the `GraphUser_V1` object.

Power **Apps** may not be able to pull the value, but Power **Automate** *can*. As a POC to get you started:

1. In Power Apps, create a button with the **Action** being running a **Power Automate Flow**.
2. Create a new flow "Power Apps button" called "GetEmployeeId".
3. In Power Automate, create a new step: **Get my profile (V2)**.

   - Under *advanced options* set **Select fields** to `employeeId`
4. Create a new step: **Parse JSON**

   - Set **Content** to the `body` of `Get my profile (V2)`:
     `@{outputs('Get_my_profile_(V2)')?['body']}`
   - Set **Schema** to:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.context": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "@@odata.id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "employeeId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

5. Create a new step: **Respond to a PowerApp or flow**
6. **Add an output** type **Text**:

   - **Enter title** : `EmployeeId`
   - **Enter in a value to respond** : `@body('Parse_JSON')?['employeeId']`
7. Save the Power Automate flow and test it. You will have to approve O365 access permissions. The whole flow should look like this:

[image: Get EmployeeId Flow]

8. Back in Power Apps, **Connect** your new flow to the app.
9. Set your `Button1.OnSelect` to: `Set( varEmployeeID, GetEmployeeId.Run())`
10. Create a label with the `Label1.Text` set to: `varEmployeeID.employeeid`
11. Run the app and click the button to test.

Answer (score 0):

I think your scenario requires to use Microsoft Graph to consumes Azure AD User Account objects, that inherits from [directoryObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/directoryobject?view=graph-rest-1.0). About this item, recommended to view similar trouble in this topic: [Get EmployeeID on Powerapps](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Get-EmployeeID-on-Powerapps/m-p/826974#M263138), that contains an example to parse in parameter an e-mail or an UserPrincipalName and returns the Active Directory employee ID.